# How to filter data in a column data frame using value in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 4032 row for 48 columns.
The first 24 columns are the fluxes calculated for several compounds and each row is the flux calculated in a time resolution of 30 min.
The following 24 columns are the calculated limit of detection (LOD) of the fluxes, for the same compounds in the previous 24 columns in the same order.

I want to see, row to row, if each compound in each column is >LOD or <-LOD for the correspetive LOD calculated for each compound in the respective column.
At the end I want to create a new dataframe where if the flux pass this condition the value is written, otherwise a NA is written.

I share a reduced versione of my dataset:

```
structure(list(mz31_fluxmax = c(0.0075314, 0.039237, -0.0091778, 
-0.0074935, -0.0062872, -0.012777), mz33_fluxmax = c(-0.10383, 
0.26369, -0.073705, -0.052205, -0.055995, -0.30571), mz39_fluxmax = c(0.13112, 
-0.24524, 0.099267, 0.14686, 0.23026, 0.2555), mz42_fluxmax = c(-0.0064381, 
0.0068372, 0.010509, 0.013523, -0.0039596, 0.018889), mz45_fluxmax = c(0.024457, 
0.10681, 0.033549, 0.034579, -0.052483, 0.057419), mz47_fluxmax = c(-0.030953, 
-0.060969, -0.027106, 0.04804, 0.048647, -0.050288), mz59_fluxmax = c(0.030912, 
0.063897, 0.03306, 0.042901, -0.032359, -0.052992), mz61_fluxmax = c(-0.013039, 
-0.018731, -0.017816, 0.035933, 0.025714, 0.023489), mz69_fluxmax = c(0.02081, 
0.021299, -0.0077438, 0.011213, 0.019074, -0.02709), mz71_fluxmax = c(0.008063, 
-0.0069763, 0.0023735, 0.0043432, 0.003758, 0.010974), mz75_fluxmax = c(-1.8245e-17, 
7.0344e-18, -0.0006465, 0.00086653, -0.00052278, 0.00056043), 
    mz79_fluxmax = c(-0.0099819, 0.029971, 0.011572, 0.009469, 
    0.02177, -0.032429), mz85_fluxmax = c(0.0068045, -0.021908, 
    0.0050362, -0.0090931, -0.0058598, -0.019743), mz87_fluxmax = c(0.0090713, 
    0.011222, 0.0051697, 0.0097271, 0.0021328, 0.0090713), mz93_fluxmax = c(-0.029838, 
    0.05316, 0.044835, 0.021252, -0.040539, 0.039774), mz99_fluxmax = c(-0.0072673, 
    0.0077081, -0.0037859, -0.0046982, -0.0010743, 0.0071997), 
    mz101_fluxmax = c(0.0048883, 0.011394, 0.0029878, -0.006759, 
    0.0065672, 0.010028), mz107_fluxmax = c(-0.027853, -0.054236, 
    0.023384, 0.022094, 0.022981, 0.036405), mz111_fluxmax = c(-0.0016328, 
    0.0066329, -0.0018345, 0.004555, 0.0015514, 0.0032013), mz113_fluxmax = c(-0.0013015, 
    0.0055934, 0.00089352, 0.0015395, -0.0011601, 0.0038798), 
    mz135_fluxmax = c(-0.0061842, -0.0098238, 0.0036505, 0.0052973, 
    0.0029078, 0.012724), mz137_fluxmax = c(0.026894, 0.034569, 
    0.016971, -0.00055361, 0.03223, 0.0020253), mz149_fluxmax = c(-0.0017587, 
    -0.0033536, 0.00090186, -0.00060427, -0.00083038, 0.0017915
    ), mz155_fluxmax = c(0.0011551, 0.00011869, 0.00052767, 0.00054035, 
    -5.7848e-05, -1.2613e-05), mz31_LOD = c(0.0056881436858662, 
    0.014850612037564, 0.00263459553228289, 0.00479935397746244, 
    0.0152440068257583, 0.0178542775892762), mz33_LOD = c(0.0125308028387973, 
    0.00911763719872646, 0.0151284350477026, 0.0372508988086331, 
    0.0402229125266234, 0.0936355242726306), mz39_LOD = c(0.0301850520395113, 
    0.0296992069156593, 0.0201949605533048, 0.217490160513958, 
    0.00223029803079041, 0.124007419481375), mz42_LOD = c(0.00320496355324591, 
    0.000990716035552583, 0.00114254522034714, 0.00153880263591558, 
    0.00948843346611039, 0.00829842969627028), mz45_LOD = c(0.0330936038635234, 
    0.0167556608587841, 0.0122716423260542, 0.000398211936512332, 
    0.00540592950218144, 0.0183693318587938), mz47_LOD = c(0.0111770867410492, 
    0.00282666705854054, 0.00172080651807461, 0.0115511710261517, 
    0.0156374551396285, 0.0544621906247567), mz59_LOD = c(0.0159506436971311, 
    0.0467280850597503, 0.00896526672250792, 0.00208209542259193, 
    0.0196628887796654, 0.00302598893847008), mz61_LOD = c(0.0016309734207739, 
    0.000905825894770442, 0.00793279030609907, 0.0131829166139475, 
    0.0108149832147901, 0.0153864222552258), mz69_LOD = c(0.00638344838052493, 
    0.00465756945316134, 0.000733281330641999, 0.00235604303405109, 
    0.00314352406984064, 0.00504395302927101), mz71_LOD = c(0.000455024687674437, 
    0.00326558077604542, 0.000174790097425541, 0.00121549851806748, 
    0.00163842732208755, 0.000892298876604984), mz75_LOD = c(NA, 
    NA, 0.00145895087681435, 4.90107803327739e-05, 0.000251573571031492, 
    0.00363292289535981), mz79_LOD = c(0.00521113925555237, 0.0103629801610154, 
    0.0118890958199121, 0.0122255131032432, 0.00536736523974168, 
    0.00568381024749507), mz85_LOD = c(0.0132788357415617, 0.00102839338218391, 
    0.00940732247246199, 0.000348774983294675, 0.00298067320381836, 
    0.00205641452275468), mz87_LOD = c(0.00201091935375826, 0.000776210717592691, 
    0.00279198390479745, 0.00141482880373932, 0.000748541000610013, 
    0.00281145814206216), mz93_LOD = c(0.00697408929207704, 0.0260339773064747, 
    0.00810401572478017, 0.00100041305177681, 0.00665795713420106, 
    0.00396693358778718), mz99_LOD = c(0.00402957819499522, 0.000566331511400743, 
    0.00155300896677703, 0.00232847303855026, 0.00464435693739678, 
    0.00171045854038109), mz101_LOD = c(0.00178420487408269, 
    0.00115586456923503, 0.00254601356943224, 0.00310985936245129, 
    0.00432584813531501, 0.00243251979505525), mz107_LOD = c(0.00407638866821389, 
    0.0229674850748965, 0.00701861441818298, 0.0116410684433383, 
    0.00485523640022218, 0.0155737255675545), mz111_LOD = c(0.000843805958946711, 
    0.00287785932050435, 0.00134575880747311, 0.000532630272225315, 
    0.00201047010477024, 0.00283236237275034), mz113_LOD = c(0.000636492422450974, 
    0.000453940678672287, 0.00108923919956853, 0.000493113580579477, 
    0.000200586155571694, 0.000500537860017757), mz135_LOD = c(0.00203273369486478, 
    0.00908905787659258, 0.000826768270592192, 0.00179533094202209, 
    0.00202657955605344, 0.00809631808214351), mz137_LOD = c(0.010197651904802, 
    0.00809757134440575, 0.00307654713824166, 0.00113203086563082, 
    0.00217444118117416, 0.00803526410617303), mz149_LOD = c(4.94861889361863e-05, 
    0.00217371652333924, 0.000952885071549479, 0.000215375843276559, 
    0.000171446563764392, 9.19079668394535e-05), mz155_LOD = c(0.000246712993094256, 
    0.00185548030033775, 9.85004369721625e-05, NA, 0.000121478907895942, 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So, to be concrete with an example:
I want to se if `mz31_fluxmax` in the first row is >`mz31_LOD` or <-`mz31_LOD`.
If the condition is respected, the value of `mz31_fluxmax` is written in the new dataframe, otherwise a NA is written.
Then so on for the next row.
Obviously, I want iterate this process for each column.

I didn't try any code.
I really don't know how do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? assuming df is your dataframe:

```
mat1 = df[,1:24]
mat2 = df[,25:48]

mat1[abs(mat1)>mat2] = NA
mat1
```

Note you have NAs on the LOD columns. Since all your values in the LOD columns are positive, your problem can be simplified to, if the absolute of the flux max is more than the LOD, set it to NA.

Comment: Thanks @StupidWolf. As I said to Ben above, this code does what I want, but partially. Because, speaking in a pratical way, you should imagine LOD as a range of positive and negative values. Values that I have in the column of LODs are positive, but I have to consider also the negative side. So, at the end LOD should be a range and all the values that are in the range are to discard, values that are out of the interval (in both positive and negative side) can be take into account.

Comment: Ok so the LOD defines the +/- range and if your values are within this, you keep the value else NA. The above should do this

Comment: Yes, Exactly! Correct.

Answer (score 2):

With `tidyverse` you could try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c("variable", ".value"), names_sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(result = if_else(abs(fluxmax) > LOD, fluxmax, as.numeric(NA)))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 144 x 4
   variable  fluxmax      LOD   result
   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 mz31      0.00753 0.00569   0.00753
 2 mz33     -0.104   0.0125   -0.104  
 3 mz39      0.131   0.0302    0.131  
 4 mz42     -0.00644 0.00320  -0.00644
 5 mz45      0.0245  0.0331   NA      
 6 mz47     -0.0310  0.0112   -0.0310 
 7 mz59      0.0309  0.0160    0.0309 
 8 mz61     -0.0130  0.00163  -0.0130 
 9 mz69      0.0208  0.00638   0.0208 
10 mz71      0.00806 0.000455  0.00806
# ... with 134 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben.
This code does what I want, but partially.
Because, speaking in a pratical way, you should imagine LOD as a range of positive and negative values. 
Values that I have in the column of LODs are positive, but I have to consider also the negative side.
So, at the end LOD should be a range and all the values that are in the range are to discard, values that are out of the interval (in both positive and negative side) can be take into account.

Comment: In this way continue to consider only the positive condition.
But because LOD is only positive value in the dataframe.

Comment: Is an assumption. LOD is always an absolute value because come from the standard deviation among several noise measurements.
Because fluxes can ben both positive and negative, LOD should be consider both in the positive and negative region, in order to have an interval.
All the positive values greater of this interval or all negative values smaller of this interval, can be taken into account.
In fact I tried something like ```if_else(abs(fluxmax) < -LOD``` but it gives me an error.
Is there a way to put in the code both conditions?

Comment: I tried. But the resulting dataframe looks like the one that come frome the first code that you shared ``` if_else(abs(fluxmax) > LOD, fluxmax, as.numeric(NA)```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206161/discussion-between-ben-and-antonio-manco).